# Передача данных через header POST'ом

Tags: php, post, авторизация, header

Ситуация такая.Есть главный домен(domen.ru),для в хода в кабинет пользователь вводит данные в domen.ru/cabinet/auth/sign_in.Там определяется все нормально с авторизацией и перекидывает его на его домен,который берется из базы(у каждого пользователя свой) например sub.domen.ru.Перекидывается через header в котором сформирован POST-запрос.
HEADER

```js
$post_data = 'username='.$_REQUEST['username']."&password=".$_REQUEST['password'];
$content_length = strlen($post_data);
$main_url=BASEDOMAIN;
$subdomain=$client->subdomain;
$location='http://'.$subdomain.".".$main_url.HTTP::getURL('cabinet');
@header('POST '.$location.' HTTP/1.1');
@header('Location: '.$location);
@header('Connection: close');
@header('Referer: '.$subdomain.'.'.$host);
@header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
@header('Content-length: ' . $content_length);
@header('');
 @header($post_data);
```

Но он остается на domen.ru и скачивает файл sign_in(он пустой).
Раньше было что использовался один домен на всех пользователей,теперь для каждого свой.

Что где не так?В переменных значения нормальные.

З.Ы.Ы.
Если первый раз тыкнул войти-скачивается файл,если второй раз тыкнул(то есть после того как скачался файл-то заходит в кабинет,но на том же домене что и был..

Помогите люди)

З.Ы.
Частично разобрался с перенаправлением-все норм,только он теперь не хочет "инициализировать" авторизацию если передаешь данные для нее

Comment: У меня ситуация проще -надо перекинуть на страничку внутри одного сайта тоже методом POST через header. Попробовал аддаптировать ваш код и ничего не вышло. У Вас в итоге это заработало? Можете упрощенный вариант написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже вы не до конца понимаете как работает HTTP. Клиент отправляет запрос серверу, а сервер формирует и отправляет обратно ответ. В вашем же коде сервер пытается отправить клиенту **HTTP запрос**, что и приводит к проблемам.

Вообще перенаправление в HTTP реализуется с помощью единственного заголовка `Location`:

```
header('Location: ' . $location);
exit();
```

Основная ваша проблема не в перенаправлении запроса, а в логике аутентификации пользователей между поддоменами. Я бы на вашем месте просто использовал одну и ту же пользовательскую сессию для основного домена и поддоменов.

**UPD:**

Посмотрите на ini параметр `session.cookie-domain` (http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain). Для общей сессии между поддоменами вам нужно указать в качестве значения что-то вроде `.domain.com`

Comment: мне нужно переправить его с главного домена на его домен и там автоматом авторизовать. чуть обновил код(для большей понятности).сейчас он переводит на домен пользователя,НО не авторизовывает его там,а авторизует только на главном,а надо наоборот...

Answer (score 0):

Открою одну маленкую тайну. Нет, даже две.
Функция header() отправляет заголовок не другому серверу. А... клиенту! То есть браузеру. Который никогда в жизни не видел заголовка 'POST ' и не представляет, что с ним делать. Не говоря уже о том, что в протоколе НТТР такого заголовка не описано в принципе.

Остальные строчки этого эпического кода, кокетливо декорированные символом @, несут примерно столько же смысла.

А кросс-доменная авторизация делается совсем по-другому. 
И сводится, как и любая другая авторизация, к выставлению куки.

Причем если все протуберации происходят в рамках одного и того же домена второго уровня с поддоменами, то никаких особенных телодвижений выполнять не надо - выставляя авторизационную куку, надо всего лишь указывать домен с точкой впереди:

.domain.com

И на всех субдоменах эта кука будет видна.

Comment: а без желчи вообще не моги?сами вы сразу сведущим стали?

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю такой костыль:

На основном домене при успешной авторизации сделайте:

```
header('location: sub.domain.com/auth.php?setcookie=COOKIE').
```

В auth.php на поддомене:

```
setcookie($_GET['setcookie']); header('location: sub.domain.com/index.php');
```