# Передача данных методом POST через header

Tags: php, post, header

Делаю редирект на страничку:

```
Header ("Location: ../mypage.php?param_n=1&param_m=2");
```

Как можно передать эти переменные методом POST? Не хочется засорять адресную строку и показывать юзеру переменные (сессию не предлагать:) ).
Редирект в рамках одного сайта.

Был уже задан похожий вопрос [Передача данных через header POST'ом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442635/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-header-post%D0%BE%D0%BC) - не смог адаптировать под свои нужды и непонятно заработал ли он у автора

Comment: See detail info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables) Maybe its helps you!

Comment: А чем сессии не угодили?

Comment: Мне надо "разделить" открытые залогиненым юзером вкладки в браузере чтобы как-то их различить, а сессия будет "одна" на весь браузер. Во-общем долго описывать)

Answer (score 0):

В том самом вопросе есть явный внятный ответ, вы не до конца понимаете логику работы **HTTP**, сначала с сервера отправите клиенту который потом уже перейдёт по определенной ссылке будет сделан **GET** запрос. 
Если бы вы с сервера делали **POST** запрос то вы бы делали его именно с сервера, а так это работа через клиента. Вы можете делать **POST** запрос с сервера по методам например **cURL**, а потом делать редиректор с каким-то одним параметром, Типа `Id=162`.

Comment: А разве я не с сервера на сервер по-сути отправляю запрос?